# Dynamically loading images as canvas background. How can I do it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm willing to create a web-page that can load images dynamically on my page. This is not all yet...

I want to dynamically create "<div..."s, inside each div, I have to create a canvas and set background images from the selected folder.

Creation of these elements would depend on the number of images inside the selected folder. All the images should be displayed as background of canvases. Each canvas will have only one image.

I want to do it using only these things:

1. HTML5
2. CSS3
3. jQuery

How do I do it?

Comment: Create Algorithm in mind or on paper. And start work on it. We can only help if you get issue or problem which seems difficult to solve. We are not going to code it for you. Maybe, someone will.

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib: Maybe you can guide me where to start? What I'm trying to figure out is: How can I dynamically create the above mentioned elements dynamically based on the number of images? How to find out the number of images inside a folder?

Comment: You can use AJAX (Client-side) to send request to PHP (Server-side) where PHP checks images in that specific folder and return data to Client. So, depending on result, create as many as you want. As you said, you want to set background of each image. So, return data as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) with the names. So, you can set it as background of canvas. As the name of folder, will already be known so, complete URL is not required. If you have any problem, add comment.

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib: Thank You very much for sharing this knowledge. I'm a beginner, so I'm not aware of these things; however, I'll try to figure it out. Secondly, I don't have to use PHP. I've to use only three things listed along with my question.

One more thing. I don't want to set background 'of each image'. I want to set images as canvas backgrounds.

I'll try to learn it by doing some homework. I appreciate your help. Thank You.

Comment: jQuery is easy for sending AJAX requests. You may first start by creating script of getting number of images in specific folder. You may use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php .

Comment: Okay, will it be possible to do it without PHP?

Comment: Skyler No. I think. Never tried without PHP. Well, Pure JavaScript is client-side not server-side.

Comment: It is but with other Serve-sider languages (like NodeJS with javascript or Ruby On rails or whatever).

Comment: Okay, let us say I don't want to make a web-page that communicates to server. This is just a html page working on a machine without internet connection. Now can I search for the images on my hard-drive and load as canvas background?

Comment: Yes but you can't access to these informations without a server side engine, even on your local machine. [HTML](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Markup_Language) is a Hypertext Markup Language and is juste there to show documents. 
Take a look at [easy php](http://www.easyphp.org/) or [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do easily do it with jQuery like that :

**Html**

```
<a href="#" class="changeFolder" data-folder="audio">Audio</a>
<a href="#" class="changeFolder" data-folder="video">Video</a>
<div id="folder">
    <!-- your canvas -->
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.changeFolder', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var folder = $(this).data('folder'),
       $folderCanvas = $('#folder');

    if(folder == 'video')
        $folderCanvas.css({'background-image': 'url(audio-img)'});
    else if(folder == 'audio')
        $folderCanvas.css({'background-image': 'url(video-image)'});                   
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/nce7C/)

On the server side you should parse the folder and find some images then call the script with [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). 
I might have misunderstand your question if so please leave a comment.

Note : I'm using the last version of jQuery.

Comment: Yes Soyuka, you've misunderstood my question. I don't want to do it server-side. I want to do it client-side. Want images to be loaded as canvas background images, from my hard-drive. Say for example, from "D:\images\".

I want to dynamically determine how many images are there in the given folder? Let us say the number of images in folder is: "X". Based on that, want to create "X" number of canvases. And set these images as background of the canvases created. Each canvas can have only one of "X" images. For example, First canvas has "1.jpg", Second one has "2.jpg" and so on. But dynamically.

Comment: You can't do that on the client side or it'll give a security lack... You'll have to parse your folders on the server side and send datas to the client side.

Comment: Thank You For You Help. If you find out something that could help me, please let me know. I'll keep trying something like this. Let's see how it works out...

Comment: Ok but you won't be able to parse folders on the client side.

Comment: Okay, let us say I don't want to make a web-page that communicates to server. This is just a html page working on a machine without internet connection. Now can I search for the images on my hard-drive and load as canvas background?